# Swift - How do I check if a firestore document exists?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I check if a Google Firebase Firestore document exists?

I've tried the following code in my project:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let UserName = UserNameText.text
print(UserName!)
let userRef = db.collection("users").document(UserName!)
    print("one")
    userRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        print("two")
        if let document = document {
            print("three")
            if document.exists{
                print("Document data: \(String(describing: document.data()))")
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a picture of my data on firebase.google.com: 
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Wlp.png)

The **print(UserName!)** will return the correct value. The following code will output **one** and **two** but will stop there.

Comment: Use `if let document = document, document.exists {`. Check out the example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: If it does not print 3, then perhaps, you are returning an error. Print out the *error* variable also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JRLtechwriting solved my problem.

"Use if let document = document, document.exists {. Check out the example here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document"